# Performance Issue with Spring Websocket, RabbitMQ and STOMP

Tags: java, spring, performance, rabbitmq, spring-websocket

I'm struggling with a performance problem for over two months now and I can not solve it. Therefore I'd like to ask for ideas what the problem could be.

### Issue

We develop an application with Spring Websocket where a client subscribes to its user queue (`/user/exchange/amq.direct/update`) to receive updates on them. I setup a JMeter test which subscribes to the user queue and sends a message every 4 seconds for a session length of 12 minutes. When having around 300 threads running (which concludes in around 4500 requests/min) the response time of the server is increasing drastically to more than 6 seconds (which I consider a timeout in my JMeter test).

The test runs on a seperate machine and the application runs on a Linux (Debian) machine with no other running application.

### What I tried already

- Exchaning the external message broker (rabbitMQ) with the internal one. Interesting is that with the internal broker I can handle up to 2000 threads, but then I get into the same timeout.
- I removed every business logic and only send a simple string as the STOMP message
- I tried different configurations for the `ClientInboundChannel` and `ClientOutboundChannel`
- I tried different `SendBufferSizeLimit` in `WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer`
- To verify that I don't have a network issue I did measure the time of an incoming message from the `ClientInboundChannel` until it gets send out in the `ClientOutboundChannel` by implementing `ChannelInterceptors` for them. This confirmed that the answer indeed needs more than 6 seconds to get send out.
- At the time where the response times over websocket get that terrible (which btw. already affects the STOMP connect call for new threads) I have no issues with traditional http requests.
- My flightrecording shows that the CPU is no issue and at a peak just at 40%, also the RAM is way below the threshold at around 1,5 GB.
- Also I can see no Thread Contention or Hot Method.
- I did not ran out of file descriptors.
- Garbage collection is no problem. I only had 4 runs within 7 minutes and the GC time is around 200-300 ms

Since I'm already working on that topic for quite a while I probably forgot a lot of things that I also tried, so please don't hesitate to start a conversation.

I hope you can give me more inspiration where to look for the issue.

### Update:

I figured out that I can increase the cachelimit of the `DefaultSubscriptionRegistry` which is used by the `SimpleMessageBroker`. This led to simply handling thousands of users with the application. So it looks like this is an issue with RabbitMQ. I did test our RabbitMQ with the [PerfTest](https://www.rabbitmq.com/java-tools.html) tool and with that test I did not had any issue. But also the test is not using the STOMP plugin, but amqp.

So is there any similar limit on the external message broker in Spring Websocket?

### Update 2:

I was able to reproduce the issue with a sample application, which you can find on github:
https://github.com/mld-ger/spring-websocket-performance-issue

Also since I believe that could be a bug in Spring I opened a ticket: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16950

Answer (score 0):

Flight Recorder only records latencies caused by monitor contention (synchronized keyword), which means other latencies, for instance caused by java.util.concurrent.* classes, may go unnoticed.

The contention could also be shorter than the default 20 ms threshold that Flight Recorder uses. This is however unlikely, since there are usually always a few outliers due to thread scheduling.

If not caused by lock contention, my guess would be that it is I/O related somehow.